# CROSS-COMPILE FOR MIPS PROCESSOR

Tags: mips32

i have developed an application for android platform.It is for ARM processor.It's working fine.I want to try the same application on Android running on MIPS(32 bit) processor.I tried to cross-compile the application but could not generate the shared library.I am using MIPS ndk and android source code customized for MIPS processor.While generating static library , it is not showing any errors but while generating the shared library,i am getting following errors:

/home/user/android-ndk-r7m/toolchains/mips-linux-android-4.4.3/prebuilt/linux-x86/bin/../lib/gcc/mips-linux-android/4.4.3/../../../../mips-linux-android/bin/ld: /home/user/workspace/testing/ccl_obj/libccl.a(teccl_call_initiate.o): relocation R_MIPS_HI16 against `__gnu_local_gp' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
/home/user/workspace/testing/ccl_obj/libccl.a: could not read symbols: Bad value
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [obj/local/mips-r2/libhello-jni.so] Error 1

Please suggest any solution.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The error seems to suggest what to do.

When compiling your source code, add the -fPIC compiler flag.

Comment: Are you sure it's being used ? Are the .c files compiled with the -fPIC flag ? You seem to have some libccl.a , what is that ? It looks like a static library, what's the relevance to that compared to the shared library you're creating ?

Comment: I am not using this -fPIC flag explicity to compile .c files.While compiling for ARM it didn't show any errors.libccl.a is the static library created after compiling the .c files.My .so file is dependant on this static library.But it is not able to read this file.

Comment: @Sujanian You have to compile the .c files that makes up libccl.a with the -fPIC flag, same with ALL your source code files that you use to create your shared object.

Comment: Can you please tell me the exact commands to compile the .c files for MIPS.The commands i am using are for ARM.I tried with those commands only and able to create static library but i think those commands are not compatible for MIPS.So,i want to know the compilation commands for MIPS.

Comment: No. I don't know how your build setup is configured, what your cross compiler is named and so on. All you have to do is add one thing,  the flag -fPIC  when you compile the source that makes up your shared library. "The source" includes *EVERYTHING*, static libraries, any source code at all that you link together to produce the shared library.

Comment: I have resolved this error.This flag was missing at many places.Thanks for your help @nos.

Answer (score -2):

Just in case if somebody face this problem.run

```
make clean 
make
```

I got similar problem today and running clean resolved my problem.